# Почему у всех блоков появился лишний отступ, хотя у body уже указана точная ширина?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  width: 1360px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.menu {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.indent {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-indent: 610px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

.banner {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 420px;
  margin: none;
}

.web1 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 130px;
  margin-top: none;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.web2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #818181;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 235px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.web3 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #818181;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 225px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.web4 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #818181;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 379px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.button {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: #10c9c3;
  background: #10c9c3;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.contact {
  margin-top: 45px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 590px;
}

.about {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.inf {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.inftext1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #818181;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.inftext2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #818181;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.inftext3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #818181;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.signature {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.skills {
  height: 520px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.smth {
  height: 520px;
  width: 680px;
  background-color: #f8f9f9;
}

.titelpr {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 250px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.design {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 435px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.procent {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 280px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}

.rectangle2 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle1 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.development {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 390px;
  margin-top: 33px;
}

.procent1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 192px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}

.rectangle4 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle3 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.marketing {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 450px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.procent2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-top: -27px;
}

.rectangle7 {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.rectangle5 {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-left: 77px;
}

.numbers {
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #10c9c3;
}

.num1 {
  margin-top: 110px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.num12 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 967px;
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.num11 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 850px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.num2 {
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: 375px;
}

.num21 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 410px;
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.num22 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: 335px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.num3 {
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: 635px;
}

.num31 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: -110px;
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.num32 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: -225px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.num4 {
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: 905px;
}

.num41 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: -630px;
  margin-top: -70px;
}

.num42 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin-right: -705px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.work {
  height: 930px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.work1 {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 30px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 110px;
}

.work2 {
  color: #818181;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.work3 {
  color: #818181;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.video {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1170px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" onMouseOut='getElementyById' (menu1).style.display="none" ; onMouseover="getElementyById" (menu1).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text indent">HOME</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">ABOUT</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu3).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">WORK</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu4).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">PROCESS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu5).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">SERVICES</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu6).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">TESTIMONIALS</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onMouseOut="getElementyById" (menu7).style.display='none' ; onmouseover="getElementyById" (menu2).style.display="block" ;>
      <p class="text">CONTACT</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<!--Banner-->
<div class="banner">
  <h2 class="web1">Web Design and Development</h2>
  <p class="web2">We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over </p>
  <p class="web3">20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two</p>
  <p class="web4">about designing websites and mobile apps. </p>
  <div class="contact">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="CONTACT US" class="button" onClick=();>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--About us-->
<div class="about">
  <h3 class="inf">About us</h3>
  <p class="inftext1">Divide have don't man wherein air fourth. Own itself make have night won't make. </p>
  <p class="inftext2">A you under Seed appear which good give. Own give air without fowl moveth dry first </p>
  <p class="inftext3">heaven fruit, dominion she'd won't very all. </p>
  <center>
    <img src="signature.png" alt="" class="signature">
  </center>
</div>
<!--Professional Skills-->
<div class="skills">
  <div class="smth">
    <h3 class="titelpr">Professional Skills</h3>
    <!--UI/UX Design-->
    <p class="design">UI/UX DESIGN</p>
    <p class="procent">75%</p>
    <!--Rectangles for UI/UX Design-->
    <div class="rectangle2">
      <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle1">
      <img src="rectangle1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <!--Web-delepoment-->
    <p class="development">WEB DEVELOPMENT </p>
    <p class="procent1">90%</p>
    <!--Rectangles for Web development-->
    <div class="rectangle4">
      <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle3">
      <img src="rectangle3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <!--marketing-->
    <p class="marketing">MARKETING</p>
    <p class="procent2">65%</p>
    <!--Rectangles for marketing-->
    <div class="rectangle7">
      <img src="rectangle2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle5">
      <img src="rectangle5.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Numbers-->
  <div class="numbers">
    <!--1-->
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c856024/v856024253/761a8/plT3ELefu64.jpg" alt="" class="num1">
    <p class="num12">548</p>
    <p class="num11">PROJECTS COMPLETED</p>
    <!--2-->
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c851024/v851024661/156c54/XzcwkcwDIug.jpg" alt="" class="num2">
    <p class="num21">1465</p>
    <p class="num22">WORKING HOURS</p>
    <!--3-->
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c850136/v850136606/17f137/o9kT2FMrfMo.jpg" alt="" class="num3">
    <p class="num31">612</p>
    <p class="num32">POSITIVE FEEDBACKS</p>
    <!--4-->
    <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c852124/v852124606/15287a/te1EI__ImnM.jpg" alt="" class="num4">
    <p class="num41">735</p>
    <p class="num42">HAPPY CLIENTS</p>
  </div>
  <!--work-->
  <div class="work">
    <h3 class="work1">Our Work Process</h3>
    <p class="work2">Was years it seasons was there form he in in them together over that, </p>
    <p class="work3">third sixth gathered female creeping bearing behold years.</p>
    <!--div for video-->
    <div class="video">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Несмотря на то, что у меня стоит ширина 1360px, экран гораздо больше. Почему?

[image: c]

Comment: Какой-то элемент (или несколько) с учётом отступов больше ширины экрана. Приведите свой `html` и `css` код. По картинке вам никто не сможет помочь.

Comment: Я добавил код..

Comment: @Air нужна твоя помощь...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, какая? Привет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в свойствах `margin-right` ваших следующих классов: `.num31, .num32, .num41, .num42`. Если их убрать, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

в css стилях измените `width:1360px` на `width:auto`;

```
body {
 width: auto;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0;
```

}

Comment: Решение товарища сверху мне не помогло кстати.

Comment: он специально задал размер, наверно, для наглядности. Если следовать вашему коду, горизонтальная полоса прокрутки не исчезнет

Comment: @Владислав Жидко , в css ` html  {  overflow-x:hidden } `

Comment: не спорю. Хороший вариант

Comment: @Владислав Жидко ,А лучшее решение - просто переделать,на мое скромное мнение конечно.